# Exploratory Factor Analysis - Factor cross-loadings

Tags: pca, spss, factor-analysis

I have read that Cross-loadings of below .3 are often ignored! Can I have some reliable references to back this up please?

I have read exisiting work and authors tend to make this decision without supporting their decision!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A factor loading of $0.30$ means that approximately $10$% of the variance in the indicator is explained by the factor (i.e., $0.30^2=0.09$). Loadings lower than this are often considered unreliable or unimportant. The extent to which model fit is affected by constraining such loadings to $0.00$ can be explored using confirmatory factor analysis (CFA). I wouldn't call this approach "ignoring" them but maybe you had a different approach in mind. If so, please clarify in the question.

**Edit**: In the comments below, I provide some possible citations. Since you seem to want a more empirical treatment of this issue, I recommend Peterson (2000).

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey. You are absolytely right in saying that. However, when I tried to find a reliable source / reference for citation in my work - It wasn't easy. Can you give a reference or two that I can cite please?

Comment: It's hard because this is more of a scientific convention than a rule or law. However, you can cite that this convention has been in use for a very long time indeed:

Fabrigar, L. R., Wegener, D. T., MacCallum, R. C., & Strahan, E. J. (1999). Evaluating the use of exploratory factor analysis in psychological research. Psychological Methods, 4(3), 272–299.

Comment: Also very relevant: Peterson, R. A. (2000). A meta-analysis of variance accounted for and factor loadings in exploratory factor analysis. Marketing Letters, 11(3), 261–275.

Comment: "[I]t seems from the general literature in the social and behavioral sciences that [a threshold factor loading of] 0.30 [is the minimum that is traditionally used when deciding to] accept an item or variable as belonging to a factor or component" -- (p. 160).

Merenda, Peter F. (1997). "A Guide to the Proper Use of Factor Analysis in the Conduct and Reporting of Research: Pitfalls to Avoid," Measurement and Evaluation in Counseling and Development 30, 156-164.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly what I was keen to get hold of.